# Emailing audio file as an attachment in IOS Swift doesn't attach file

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send an mp4 audio file as an attachment using MessageUI

I have a tableview with different files that the user can choose to send and when the user slides the row and taps on the email option, an email form should pop up along with the file that will be send. I'm able to find the file location but not load the data. Here's my code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    let mail = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Mail") { action, index in
        let mailComposeViewController = self.configureMailController()

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            if let filePath = URL(string: self.filesArray[indexPath.row]) {
                print(filePath)
                if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: String(describing: filePath)) {
                    print("file data loaded")
                    mailComposeViewController.addAttachmentData( fileData as Data, mimeType: "audio/mp4", fileName: self.filesArray[indexPath.row])

                }
            }
            self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showMailError()
        }
    }
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: self.getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row).mp4"))

        self.filesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.fileDateInfoArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.fileStamps.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.filesArray, forKey: "arrayOfRecordedFiles")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.fileDateInfoArray, forKey: "arrayOfDates")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.fileStamps, forKey: "arrayOfTimeStamps")
    }
    return [delete, mail]
}


func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Citrus Piano")

    return mailComposerVC
}

func showMailError() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not send email", message: "Your device could not send email", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
    self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: String(describing: filePath)) {  What's this line?

Comment: Try zipping the file. The email attachment does not support many types

Comment: @ElTomato that's to load the file and to convert it to NSData to later use as Data object

Comment: can you post the string that you are trying to initialize your URL?

Comment: @ElTomato OP should use `Data` not `NSData` since Swift 3

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, I basically was not setting up the filename and thus the filename and full filename with path would get mixed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using function as below to attach a audio file

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["iosGeek@gmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("New Request")

        // locate folder containing audio file
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let AudioFileNameToBeAdded = (documentsPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("/yourFolderName/\(audioFileNameAtIndex)")
        let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: AudioFileNameToBeAdded)
        mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(fileData! as Data, mimeType: "audio/wav", fileName: self.audioFileNameAtIndex)

    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
    return mailComposerVC
}
```

My output :

[image]

I think in your case 
Function might to be

-> **if you are saving file inside a folder**

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["iosGeek@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("New Request")

            // locate folder containing audio file
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let AudioFileNameToBeAdded = (documentsPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("/yourFolderName/\(audioFileNameAtIndex)")
            let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: AudioFileNameToBeAdded)
            mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(fileData! as Data, mimeType: "audio/mp4", fileName: self.audioFileNameAtIndex)

        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
        return mailComposerVC
    }
```

-> **if you are directly saving it in directory**

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["iosGeek@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("New Request")

            // locate folder containing audio file
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let AudioFileNameToBeAdded = (documentsPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(audioFileNameAtIndex)
            let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: AudioFileNameToBeAdded)
            mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(fileData! as Data, mimeType: "audio/mp4", fileName: audioFileNameAtIndex)

        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
        return mailComposerVC
    }
```

For Crash At - Line `mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(fileData! as Data, mimeType: "audio/mp4", fileName: self.audioFileNameAtIndex`)
is maybe due to wrong path you are providing 
if possible can I see what method you are using to get the document directory path ? is file you want to share is in other directory inside main directory

**Note: Just use this few lines to access your file**

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)[0]
let AudioFileNameToBeAdded = (documentsPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(audioFileNameAtIndex)
let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: "/folderNameIfAny/\(audioFileNameAtIndex)")
```

Comment: I tried your code and I get a crash that says "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". This is on the line of code of addAttachmentData

Comment: Force-wrapping an NSData object is not a very smart choice.

Comment: @buttonSmasher96 did you provide correct mime Type ?

Comment: @iOSGeek I think so, my file type is mp4 so I put "audio/mp4" as mim type

Comment: @ElTomato is it because the possibility of the file not existing?

Comment: @buttonSmasher96 I edited my answer please check and tell me is it working for you or not ? you need to check path you are providing there as it worked for me I used it in my project just now to check. else if possible can share project file so, I check it

Comment: happy to help, Welcome